# Drag UIButton on long press in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new in iPhone development.

I want to create one application in which whenever user long presses the button, it will be shaken and user is able to drag it on the screen and he will also be able to change its location.

I have tried this code.

```
 - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender 
    { 
       NSLog(@"Long press called!!!!");
    }
```

Comment: are you asking how to create something like the springboard / home screen on an iPhone?

Comment: Post more code. You have chosen correct method. Add some functionality in this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the MoveMe sample app. It will show you how to allow movement of subviews by touch and drag.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html

you can also download that sample code ... :)